# Size of the usable space

Tags: javascript, html

probably i need size of the vertical sidebars. I calcuate spacer: take whole screen height.
On some devices screen.outerHeight gives me whole height on the another it is only usable space.
How to get only usable space on android devices to do good spacer?

```
  String( window.outerHeight-
  document.querySelector('.container2').offsetHeight-
  document.querySelector('.webdesign').offsetHeight-40
  )+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use,

```
window.innerHeight
```

to get the height of usable space.

[image]